# Pushing results to DB

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and am trying to push the property value of an object when it is changed in my app. For instance:

```
List 1
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter : {selected: false}">
    {{ item.name }}
    <a href="#" ng-click="move(item)">move</a>
  </li>
</ul>

List 2
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter : {selected: true}">
    {{ item.name }}
    <a href="#" ng-click="move(item)">move</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So in this app, when I click "move" it changes the selected property to true or false. However in the DB this is not reflected. How can I post these as AJAX requests to achieve persistence?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $http to make an ajax call before changing the item's state. Something like...

```
$scope.move = function(item) {
    var newState = !item.selected;
    $http.post(someurl, item).success(function() {
        item.selected = newState;
    });
};
```

Comment: What should I return in my post route? I.E. `Route::post('items', function()
{
    return Item::all();
});` That code gives no errors, but does not persist the updated data